# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2021-09-22'

Tags: python, linear-regression

I'm trying to run this python script,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
dataset= pd.read_csv('Desktop/Yahoo_Finance.csv')
dataset.head()
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:2].values
y = dataset['Close']
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
classifier = LinearRegression()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Yahoo Finance Stock Prices")
plt.plot(y_pred[:50],linewidth=3.0)
```

but im getting the following error,
[this is the error showing up on google colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkYbd.png)

Comment: why you converting a date to float??

Comment: What you are trying to do, has barely any sense in terms of making regression. What you are trying to do, is to make date as a predictor, which most likely you don't want to do - drop this column and move on. Unless, if you want to consider date variable, then do it by applying t=1,2,3,...,n to X values.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to convert the date column into datetime type before scaling.